# Energy method for linear advection

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I found this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem) about **well-posedness** of PDEs and the **energy method**. They consider the following problem
the advection problem
$$ u(t,x):[0,T]\times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , \quad s.t.
\begin{cases}
    \displaystyle
    \partial_t u + \alpha \partial_x u = 0,\\
    u(0,x) = f(x),\\
    u(t,0) = u(t,1) = 0.\\
\end{cases}
$$

From here they multiply the equation by $u$, integrate over $[0,1]$ and use the BC:
$$
    \partial_t \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u^2 dx = -\alpha \int_0^1 u \partial_x u = -\alpha \int_0^1 \partial_x \left ( \frac{u^2}{2} \right ) dx = - \alpha \left. \frac{u^2}{2}   \right|_0^1 = 0,
$$

which shows boundedness of the $L^2$ norm (or i guess "energy"?) of $u$. In fact, if we now integrate over $[0,T]$, we obtain
$$\begin{aligned}
    \int_0^T \partial_t \Vert u \Vert_2 dt &= 0\\
    \Vert u(T,x) \Vert_2 - \Vert\underbrace{ u(0,x) }_{=f(x)}\Vert_2 &= 0.
\end{aligned}$$

But the wikipedia article states an **inequality** as the result:
$$\Vert u(T,x) \Vert_2 \leq \Vert f(x)\Vert_2$$

Where is the $\leq$ coming from?

---

**My idea:** It might be, because they suddenly consider more general, non-zero boundary conditions for which
$$\Vert u(T,x) \Vert_2 = \Vert f(x)\Vert_2 - \alpha \left. \frac{u^2}{2}   \right|_0^1.$$

Now let $u(t,0)^2<u(t,1)^2$, and $\alpha>0$, meaning that intuitively we have a "net outflow of high solution values" at $x=1$. In this case, the estimate becomes:
$$\Vert u(T,x) \Vert_2 = \Vert f(x)\Vert_2 - \underbrace{\alpha [u(t,1)^2-u(t,0)^2]}_{>0}\leq \Vert f(x)\Vert_2$$

The same works in the case of a net outflow at $x=0$, but not for net inflows at either $x=0$ or $x=1$.

---

1. Is my idea correct?
2. Why does it show well-posedness, i.e. why does it show uniqueness or existence of solutions?

---

**EDIT**:

1. the wikipedia article changed not long after i posted the question here (maybe even because of my question?). The article linked above now discussed the same procedure for the diffusion equation, and explains the concepts much better.
2. The problem i have discussed above is problematic, as I assume an outflow BC. This BC is too much and should not be posed. In the proof of uniqueness of solutions, and in the proof of continuous dependence on IC and BC, this turns out to be problematic.

Comment: Sometimes one writes only an inequality in place of an equality since that's enough. Usually, when working with weak solutions, that's all you can get, and equality holds only for smooth solutions. Regarding uniqueness, do you know which equation solves the difference between two solutions? In particular, which initial value does it have?

Comment: Assuming an inequality instead of an equality seems to be a very bad idea, as we arrive at the opposite esimate $\Vert u(T,x) \Vert_2 \geq \Vert f(x)\Vert_2$ if e.g. we change the sign of $\alpha$, or am I missing somthing? The difference of any two solutions solves the problem with $f(x)\equiv 0$, from which we get $u\equiv 0$, so we have uniqueness. But we have not shown existence of solutions, right?

Comment: Also i just realized that assuming non-zero BC, we can not use the same technique to show uniqueness, as the difference of two solutions does not satisfy the BC. In this case, do we have to pose the problem on an affine space, and then "lifting" it to a proper vector space, then show uniqueness and go back to the affine space with non-zero BC?

Comment: I don't see how the sign of $\alpha$ plays any role in your computation. The difference between the two solutions with non-zero boundary conditions has homogeneous boundary conditions, and your inequality shows uniqueness.

Comment: And no, existence has to be shown separately. But apriori bounds like this one play usually a main role in doing so.

Comment: If the sign of $\alpha$ changes, then $\alpha [u(t,1)^2-u(t,0)^2]$ has a different sign, and i would arrive at $\Vert u \Vert_2$ equal $\Vert f \Vert_2$ minus something positive. So  $\Vert f \Vert_2$ is then smaller than $\Vert u \Vert_2$, correct?

Comment: Ah, that's what you're referring to. If the solutions has non-zero boundary conditions, then the inequality is in general false, yes. You get additionally terms corresponding to the boundary values of $u$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: So are you saying: "my idea" from above (concerning the signs for $\alpha$ and the BC) is incorrect/meaningless and the equality only holds for zero BC? Moreover, may I ask, why you didnt answer in a post, but in a comment?

Comment: Well, your idea works in that particular case, i.e., if $u(t,0)^2 < u(t,1)^2$. But in general, this is of course not given, and in that case, the norms of the boundary values appear on the right-hand side in the energy inequality. I haven't written an answer since I don't have a complete answer to your questions and wanted to encourage you to do some things on your own instead of providing a full solution (as for the uniqueness).

Comment: Thank you for your ideas!